# How to get the location of the program you're running and store it in a File object

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to find a way to reference my java program in order to check whether or not it's up-to-date, and I was wondering whether or not there is a special way of referring to it? For example, the person runs the program (I don't know where it is) and I want to compare it to a file I have on my web server to make sure it's up-to-date, but to do this I must have it stored in a File object in order to compare it to the one on my web server, how do I go about doing that? Is there a special way to find the location of the program that's being run?

Something like this:

```
File thisProgram = new File(?);
```

Not sure what to put inside the parenthesis in order to reference the program itself.

Comment: What if you're running from a network-downloaded jar that doesn't reside on the filesystem at all, or an unexploded .war? This question has no portable answer.

Comment: Let's assume they arent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file